# Make form back color = textbox input

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a textbox, i want the user to be able to type like a color code or something in the textbox and the form back color to change to the specific color the user typed.
Help?

Comment: Please show us your attempt as I would say by the dv's and close flags you have it would be a good recomendation...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you mean that the user will be typing in something like `black` or `blue` then you need the `.GetColorFromName` function. The code below takes the text from `TextBox1` and checks to make sure that the color is recognized. If so, the Form.BackColor is set to that colour. This way if the user mis-types a color, you wont get an error. Also, it doesn't seem to matter if you type `black` or `Black`

```
Dim c As Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(TextBox1.Text)
If c.IsKnownColor Then
    Me.BackColor = c
End If
```

If you want to add a keyword "color" to the begining of the textbox, try this instead ..

```
Dim commandString As String = TextBox1.Text
If commandString.ToLower.StartsWith("color") Then
    'remove the 5 letters making "color" and a space
    commandString = commandString.Remove(0, 6)
    Dim c As Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(commandString)
    If c.IsKnownColor Then
        Me.BackColor = c
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Comment: @PrestonL Interesting that somebody downvoted a perfectly good answer tho. If you wouldn't mind clicking on the tick next to my answer, that would be great, as it helps other users in the same situation as you see that this answer works. Cheers

Comment: How could I make it where the user has to type something like "color:" before typing the color in order to change the backcolor?

Comment: No worries, see my updated answer .